# Restructuring pattern matching

Tags: scala, dictionary, data-structures, pattern-matching

I have a datastructure which is created as such:

```
// [Measure -> [Installation -> [Year -> [Month -> [Day -> [Hour -> BigDecimal] ]]]]]
private var dayList = new mutable.HashMap[String, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]]]]]()
```

The reason for this is that I want to be able to look this mapping up to get my data.

However, in scala to insert into this datastructure I get something like this:

```
    dayList.get(col) match {
        case Some(measureLook) =>
          measureLook.get(installation) match {
            case Some(instaLook) =>
              instaLook.get(tempYear) match {
                case Some(yearLook) =>
                  yearLook.get(tempMonth) match {
                    case Some(monthLook) =>
                      monthLook.put(tempDay, hourCounter)
                    case None =>
                      val m = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]()
                      m.put(tempDay, hourCounter)
                      yearLook.put(tempMonth, m)
                  }
                case None =>
                  val y = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]]()
                  val m = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]()
                  m.put(tempDay, hourCounter)
                  y.put(tempMonth, m)
                  instaLook.put(tempYear, y)
              }
            case None =>
              val in = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]]]()
              val y = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]]()
              val m = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]()
              m.put(tempDay, hourCounter)
              y.put(tempMonth, m)
              in.put(tempYear, y)
              measureLook.put(installation, in)
          }
        case None =>
          val me = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]]]]()
          val in = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]]]()
          val y = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]]()
          val m = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.HashMap[Int, BigDecimal]]()
          m.put(tempDay, hourCounter)
          y.put(tempMonth, m)
          in.put(tempYear, y)
          me.put(installation, in)
          dayList.put(col, me)
      }
```

Which to me is insane amount of code. And I feel like this could be shortened down somehow, but I don't see the solution.

Because I have to look up the elements, and if it exists, then I can easily insert into the elements.

However if the elements somewhere in the chain does not exist, then I have to create the element and of course all the sub elements, as you can see in the code above.

Do you have any ideas as how I can do this more clean or maybe use a more organized datastructure for this?

Comment: Use for comprehension. If you provide some sample data I can write an example.

Comment: Well I have some output from the MongoDB that I am using. http://pastebin.com/12n6Tre7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider defining a case class for each

```
[Measure -> [Installation -> [Year -> [Month -> [Day -> [Hour -> BigDecimal]]]]]]
```

namely for instance,

```
case class Data(Measure: String,
                Installation: String
                date: java.util.Date,
                n: BigDecimal)
```

Collect all into an `Array[Data]` which can be *indexed* onto a `Map` by a field of interest.

**Update**

A depiction on indexing on `Measure` and `Installation`,

```
val info[Array[Data]] = Array(data_1,..., data_n)
val meInsIdx = info.map ( d => (d.Measure,d.Installation) -> d ).toMap
```

Note `Map` keys need be unique. To query for a `data_i` in `meInsIdx` consider for instance

```
val data_i = meInsIdx.get(measure_i, installation_i)
```

which delivers an `Option[Data]` (either `Some(data_i)` or `None` for a key not present).

Comment: I think your solution is the best I can think of. Handling it with pairs could also work. But of course handing them around would be a pain in the a, especially in function calls as parameters. 
Thank you for your solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by indexing the `Array[Data]` onto the Map? Could you show me a code of example?

Comment: I see now. I will try to implement this.